# How to store the image to other directory using ASP.NET and need to override the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

My application is running in c drive but i have to store the image from database to the folder which is in another drive(D drive) how can i do that? And also the image name should be same i.e. i need to omit the filename and should give the default name for that image and have to read it from that particular drive by simply giving the path "D:\foldername\defaultnameof_file.extension";. in other application

Could you please help me on this issue.

Thanks,
Padmanaban

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried? What fails? It's too obvious...

Comment: Make sure the "user" running the website has write access to the folder where you store the files.

Comment: i need to upload and update the image on database at the same time what image that i have updated or uploaded should be stored in the folder (whenever am updating or uploading that should orverride the previous image so i want to give the same name for that image) default name. so that i can easily fetch the image by simply giving the name of it. How can i do it? I have tried it but not succeded.

Comment: @JotaBe it is ok and working fine now, but my concern is if iam placing this code in a production server then i dont knw, How could it wil be effective at working... let me check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
{
    FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"D:\foldername\defaultnameof_file.extension");
    Label1.Text = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName ;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"D:\foldername\defaultnameof_file.jpg"); //if you saving jpg file
        Label1.Text = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName ;
    }
```

If you database contains the file name with extension then just provide the name...

```
String imageName = //your code to fetch imagename (eg. demo.jpg)
if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"D:\foldername\" + imageName); 
            Label1.Text = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName ;
        }
```

OR if imageName does not have extention...

```
 if (FileUpLoad1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpLoad1.SaveAs(@"D:\foldername\" + imageName + ".jpg"); 
            Label1.Text = "File Uploaded: " + FileUpLoad1.FileName ;
        }
```

Comment: It is working but not able to display the image from that folder. it storing the image as defaultnameof_file.extension which is not a image or valid file! how to get save the exact image file? with default name!!

Comment: @nick Thanks it works upto some extent... i will reach you if there any problem araises. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Padmanaban actually extension is written only for explanation the actual code should contain the extention of image file like .jpg , .png etc... see the edit in my answer..